# Are there consumer-grade VPN services that support two-factor authentication, like SecurID?

Tags: network, authentication, multi-factor, vpn

I'd like to increase my VPN security, and Google hasn't turned up anything with regard to VPN services and SecurId.

Does anyone know of services like this?

Comment: Heh, nowadays it's questionable if using SecurId will actually increase your security, or decrease it ;)

Comment: Do you specifically want SecurID (despite the recent [RSA hack and unrelenting shroud of secrecy around the technology and how compromised it now is](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/))?  Or do you want a service that supports clearly good two-factor authn?

Comment: Edited the title.  @Javoid - Please correct me if I mis-read your intentions.

Comment: The title is now more accurate, thank you. It doesn't have to be SecureId, but I'd like to see a hardware dongle style authorization, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You could roll your own easily for cheap or free using Amazon's micro EC2 instances (http://aws.amazon.com/free) and our free two-factor auth from Duo (http://duosecurity.com) - either SSH-tunnelled (e.g. ssh -D 1080 my.ec2.host and set your local SOCKS proxy configuration to localhost:1080), or else using OpenVPN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any that autenticate independently, but there are many that will authenticate against a SecurID authentication server. PIX appliances, for example, support this. Try http://www.google.com/search?q=cisco+securid+vpn

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking more for a service that provides VPN for x dollars a month, that also uses SecurId verification.

Answer (score 0):

They don't provide the VPN itself so not sure if this is quite what you're after but [Signify](http://www.signify.net/) offer a hosted RSA SecurID service. They send you a token and you configure your VPN gateway to talk, over t'Internet to their RADIUS servers for authentication. Pricing is reasonable iirc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the service as well.  I don't want to create my own VPN.  I'm surprised it's so difficult to find a two-factor authentication VPN service for consumers or small businesses.

Comment: @Javoid - it's because VPN services for big businesses are very profitable, so they pay back the relatively high initial costs quickly. For small businesses the initial costs aren't that much cheaper, but they need to charge a higher per-user cost to make it pay back.

Answer (score 0):

Hamachi employs two factor authentication - they describe a public-private key pair in their
[security white paper](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/documentation/EN/pdf/Hamachi2/LogMeIn_Hamachi2_SecurityWhitepaper.pdf). Combined with the required network password you have a two factor consumer VPN solution (although neither of the factors is a token and a shared password's reliability decreases the more people that know it).

As an alternative you could look at a hosted openVPN solution such as dotBlock's openVPN stack; with full console access you could install [WikID](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wikid-twofactor/).